# classification real vs. made-up words

Tags: classification, natural-language, feature-engineering, information-geometry

I am interesting in building a classifier that can separates made-up words (such as brands) from real words (belonging to the English dictionary for example).
I have tried using a [Soundex representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex) + Euclidean geometry: it does not work well. If you [MDS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multidimensional_scaling), it looks like this: [image: red: brands; blue: english]

In red, brands are displayed; english words in blue.

Thus, I am looking for ideas or better empirical/theoretical studies that tackle this problem.